# Is there any option where we can check the source of the AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am working on a django project where in views i have defined a viewset which returns a queryset.
I want to use if else condition in the viewset similar to:

```
if AJAXrequest from xyz.js
{
//do this
}
else if AJAXrequest from abc.js
{
//do that.
}
```

May i please get help as i am not able to get any help from other related questions and blogs.

EDIT:
AJAX request from xyz.js calls the viewset and returns a queryset object.
AJAX request from abc.js calls the viewset with a list and returns a queryset object.

EDIT2:

```
class UserViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

if request.is_ajax(): 
    if 'user.js' in request.GET.get('users', ''):
        print " called from user.js"

else:
    print "called from info.js"
```

Comment: Check [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your ajax

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/yoururl/',
   type: 'get',
   data: {'js': 'abc.js'}
})
```

and in your view:

```
def yourview(request):
    if request.is_ajax(): 
        if 'abc.js' in request.GET.get('js', ''):
            # do this
        else:
            # do that
```

Comment: one additional question, since ajax req from xyz.js doesnt contain data attribute, can i just do if 'somedata' in request.GET.get(' ')  will it satisfy the condition for the second ajax req only.

Comment: @vaibhav-1616 the `else` part already covers the `xyz` part, right?

Comment: I mean that instead of sending the js file name, can i just check if the ajax req contains any data and if it contains that is for abc.js.

Comment: @vaibhav-1616 thats up to your own business logic. Your question is different than what you are asking right  now.. of course you can do it, but how do you want to `do this` and `do that` if you dont send any data?

Comment: i am  getting an error : NameError: name 'request' is not defined
do i need to install the library using pip install request or is there any workaround

Comment: i have added the snippet from my code.please check.Thnx a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can post the source information on data attribute of $.ajax function.

Comment: i am getting an error : NameError: name 'request' is not defined do i need to install the library using pip install request or is there any workaround

Comment: can you paste code which you have used for ajax call ?